# Assign filename dynamically in a response

Tags: php, xml, laravel, response

in my web application created with Laravel 8, I need to download an .xml file and the file name must be dynamically created, as per the title.
this is because the file name is composed following a specific rule and having to include today's date.

`$filename = 'FirstPart_'.date("Y-m-d").'_000.xml'`

so far to test the response and therefore the download I have given a fixed name to the file, as follows, and the download is performed correctly.

- code with fixed filename

```
        $response = Response::create($xml, 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
        $response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="TestXMLDownload.xml"');
        $response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        return $response;
```

But when i try to download the file with my custom filename, the download fails.

- code with custom filename

```
        $response = Response::create($xml, 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
        $response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="".$filename.""');
        $response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        return $response;
```

I appreciate any suggestion or advice

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Have you checked whether you are using quotes properly? `'attachment; filename="".$filename.""'` will not include the dynamic file name

Comment: @NicoHaase, in the the second case, the download not start...yes i've checked the quotes, and tried also `$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"')`;

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: `""` will result in a syntax error. you need to escape the quote that is meant to be part of the string e.g. `\""`

Comment: @NicoHaase i've tried with different exaping quotes, first I thought that might be the problem, and then I searched online for examples...

Comment: @apokryfos i've tried this, but don't work...i have no idea

Comment: Share what you tried w.r.t. escaping and how it didn't work (e.g. are there any errors shown or in the logs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have a error in this line, In this case "$filename" append in your header not dynamic file name value.

```
$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="".$filename.""');
```

**try this solution:**

```
$filename = "TestXMLDownload.xml";

$response = Response::create($xml, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
$response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
$response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');

//change that line in your code

$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . '"' . $filename . '"');

$response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');

return $response;
```

Append $filename in your filename that pass tp $response->header.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. `filename=' . '"'` looks strange to me

Comment: filename=' . '"' . $filename . '"' appends the value of $filename in string, but in another way it just append "$filename" as string.

Comment: Thank's i've solved...i've really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. PHP accepts dynamic filename through specific single quotes. I have changed the format of the quotes here.

```
$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why? As far as I see, the OP has used that code without success